# Firebase recycler adapter not functioning

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter For the first time, but it just never gets called! I've checked the [Firebase Guide Here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) but no good.

Have also checked similar threads that reported "Deleting Has FixedSize()" fixed it for them but that's not the case Here

[Here's part of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAMyK.png)

and Here's my code for the adapter and model:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Complaint, ComplaintHolder> TestAdapter;
DatabaseReference mRef;
FirebaseUser mUser;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("AccountsComplaintBasdNode").child(mUser.getUid());


    Query query = mRef;


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Complaint> mOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Complaint>()
            .setQuery(query, Complaint.class)
            .build();


    if (TestAdapter == null) {

        TestAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Complaint, ComplaintHolder>(mOptions) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ComplaintHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please get called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return new ComplaintHolder(v);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ComplaintHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Complaint model) {

                holder.TitleTv.setText(model.getComplaintTitle());
                SimpleDateFormat smf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                String dateString = smf.format(model.getDate());
                holder.DateTv.setText(dateString);

            }


///Model Object here

 public Complaint() {
}

private String ComplaintTitle;
private String details;
private Date mDate;
private String PhotoUrl;



public Complaint(String complaintTitle, String details, Date date, String photoUrl) {
    ComplaintTitle = complaintTitle;
    this.details = details;
    mDate = date;
    PhotoUrl = photoUrl;
}

public void setComplaintTitle(String complaintTitle) {
    ComplaintTitle = complaintTitle;
}

public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.mDate = date;
}

public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    PhotoUrl = photoUrl;
}

public String getComplaintTitle() {
    return ComplaintTitle;
}

public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return PhotoUrl;
}
```

Comment: Have you set `TestAdapter.startListening();` in `onStart()`?

Comment: Holy shit it Worked! real awesome bro

Comment: Would you mind putting your answer in a comment  so I could accept it properly and perhaps elaborate a little on how it worked?

Comment: Especially that the documentation doesn't mention its necessity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the `startListening()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling `startListening()` or your query will fail.

So seems only you need is to call `TestAdapter.startListening();` in `onStart()` method and don't forget to call `TestAdapter.stopListening();` in `onStop()` as well but before calling `stopListening()` always check agains `null` 
like:`if(TestAdapter != null)`

For more information and example: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md